# How can I get thumbnail image from multipartfile video without storing it in local storage

Tags: spring

I'm trying to make thumbnail image from multipartfile video input.

Below logic is I'm trying to:

1. Spring receive uploaded video as multipartFile from user
2. Store video directly in s3
3. Extract thumbnail image from video in Java using jcodec
4. Store thumbnail image in s3

AWS Media Convert needs to convert full video as well, so the price is too expensive to use.
I just want only one frame/image from video and store it.
I've tried ffmpeg as well, but it needs storeing video in local area which I don't want.
Is there any easier way to get thumbnail image.. or is it possible to get from front-end?